# How to measure mouse's travel distance?

Tags: java, mouse, awtrobot, measurement

I want to measure mouse's travel distance for a pet project. So I want to set up an experiment: let's say how precise can I get the travel distance in 1m.

I tried to write test program but I got some difficulties:Screen border.

I'm using Robot class to set the mouse position when it's about to reach the edge but I'm not sure this is right. Do you know any technique how to unbound the screen or any other solution that would work?

Here's my test code:

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws AWTException {
        Toolkit toolkit = new WToolkit();
        int screenResolution = toolkit.getScreenResolution();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        List<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
        int distance = 0;
        while (true) {
            if(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y <= 50)
            {
                robot.mouseMove(910, 1080);
            }
            list.add(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getLocation());
            if(list.size() >= 2) {
                Point p2 = list.get(list.size()-1);
                Point p1 = list.get(list.size()-2);
                if(p2.getY() <= p1.getY()) {
                    distance += (int) Math.sqrt(0 + Math.pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2));  // sqrt(pow(x2-x1) + pow(y2-y1))  sqrt(pow(x2-x1) = 0 for just measure on Y
                    System.out.println(distance / screenResolution * 0.0254);
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch ( Exception e) {
                System.out.println("something");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yea I would like to use mouse's optical sensor for a robot. With the sensor I want to measure the distance the robot moved. So that's why I want find out if it's possible with a mouse sensor.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in Java.  A `MouseInfo` can only give you the current location of the mouse pointer - it can't measure beyond the edges of the `GraphicsDevice` that you're on.  (Whoops, I typed that in the wrong box at first).

Comment: Why are you squaring then square-rooting `p2.y - p1.y` ?

Comment: It's because of distance formula: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm
I left out x cause first I just want to check it on straight move, so x won't disturb the result.

Comment: Do check out `Math.hypot` then.

Comment: yea thanks, I can use that

Answer (score 1):

In this solution, you would be constantly updating Points p1 and p2 to find the distance traveled overall between updates

```
//I think this code should work for what you are doing
double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.getX()-p2.getX(),2)+Math.pow(p1.getY()-p2.getY(),2));
```